# MongoDB: Is there a way to limit a dataset based on an array of values?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB and Python to limit a dataset based on user input. The format of the documents in MongoDB are in the following screenshot attached below:

[image]

I am trying to make a shortened version of this dataset (which I can then randomly select a document from) based on user input. For instance, the input would be an array with these values: [1,2,3,5,7,9]. Using this array and the big dataset of all of the chapters, I would then limit the dataset to only the documents that contain chapters 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, and 9. Is there a simple and fast way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add an input and desired output example?

Comment: Input value: [1,2,3,5,7,9]
Output value: All the documents with chapters 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, and 9.
I'm looking for a mongodb command that can do this.

Comment: Try using [collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.find/)

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XUty4R2kvX-) what are you looking for? I can add an answer to explain in a better way if this is correct.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to find by values inside an array.

```
db.collection.find({
  "Chapter": {
    $in: [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      5,
      7,
      9
    ]
  }
})
```

This query tells mongo "Find all documents where `Chapter` has a value inside the array".

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XUty4R2kvX-)